# Error while reading a data from a file

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I am using below program to read a data from a file. I am getting false when i try to validate the existence of file.File is present though

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("H:\\infilename.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Getting below error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\infilename.txtt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at BufferedReaderExample.main(BufferedReaderExample.java:15)
```

I am always getting error when i try to read a file in my systems. I am using eclipse. It is not installed on my system. It is a standalone application.is that causing a problem here? PLease help me on this

Comment: file is not found. Is it there?

Comment: I'd recommend checking H:\\ to actually verify that the file is there.

Comment: choose an answer that can help people stumbling later.@user3830868

Answer (score 2):

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("H:\\infilename.txtt"));
```

Typing error mainly; you spelled the name of the file wrong. You should instead write:

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("H:\\infilename.txt"));
```

[image: Notepad]

[image: Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't exist.

Please, make sure it does exist before you use it:

```
{
    final File file = new File("H:\\infilename.txt");
    if(file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        // ...
    } else System.out.println("File not found!");
}
```

And if need be, create it:

```
{
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

---

As mentioned by OP, the problem was that the file was saved with `.txt` as a suffix. Removing it will resolve the problem.

Comment: @user3830868 Excellent. I've added that into my answer so that this answer may be helpful for future readers. Feel free to mark it as correct with the checkmark to the left of my answer to close the question.